# An analytic function $f(z)$ on $U$ can be decomposed as $ f(z)=f_1(z)+f_2(z) $

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be simple closed curves in $\mathbb C$ and assume that $C_2$ is in the interior of $C_1$. Let $U$ be the region bounded by $C_1$ and $C_2$.
>
> Prove that an analytic function $f(z)$ on $U$ can be decomposed as $$ f(z)=f_1(z)+f_2(z) ,$$ where $f_1(z)$ is analytic in the interior of $C_1$ and $f_2(z)$ is analytic in the exterior of $C_2$(including $\infty$). Moreover the decomposition is unique up to an additive constant.

---

My Attempt:

If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are circles then we know that $f_1(z)$ are the terms in the Laurent series with non-negative power, and $f_2(z)$ are those with negative power. Otherwise, we can imitate the important technique to prove the Laurent series locally so that we can still treat it as is the circle(since within a small angle, it preserves the inequalities and we can write $\frac{1}{\zeta-z}=\frac{1}{\zeta-z_0+z_0-z}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{z_0-z}{\zeta-z_0}}\cdot\frac{1}{\zeta-z_0}$ and use the Talor series of $\frac 1{1-z}$). Then since the closed curve is also compact, we can get finitely many expansions of $f(z)$ at different parts of the curve. Finally, since the Laurent series is unique locally, then we can glue each part to get a Laurent series of $f(z)$ in $U$. Does this work?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on the closure you can apply the Cauchy Integral Formula on $C_1\oplus C_2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I know this. But how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Shift $C_1,C_2$ slightly so that $f$ is analytic on an open containing $U$ and them.

From the Cauchy integral formula (the one for simply connected domains, adding an edge to make $U$ simply connected, edge which disappears since traversed in two opposite directions)

For $z$ in between the two simple closed curves $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_1} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds-\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_2} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$$ It is immediate that this is your decomposition.

When $C_1,C_2$ are circles expanding $\frac{1}{s-z}$ in geometric series in $s/z,z/s$ is how you get the Laurent series.

Comment: How to conclude that the decomposition is unique up to an additive constant?

Comment: What if it is not..

Comment: Replace $f_1,f_2$ by $f_1+e^z,f_2-e^z$. Where is the problem ? (also $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_2} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$ is a Laurent series)

Comment: No. Where is the problem with $f_1+e^z,f_2-e^z$ ?

Comment: $e^z$ isn't "analytic at $\infty$" ($e^{1/s}$ has an essential singularity at $s=0$). Without asking $f_2$ is analytic at $\infty$ the decomposition isn't unique. Liouville says there is no non-constant function analytic everywhere including $\infty$

Comment: I just did ${}{}$

Comment: Have you founded how it works ? If $f_1 + h,f_2-h$ is another decomposition, then $h$...

Comment: I gave $f_1,f_2$ in my answer, the problem of unicity is about $h$

Comment: I gave all the clues... $h$ is constant because ...

Comment: The uniqueness works as for the Laurent decomposition: Assume that $f = f_1 + f_2 = g_1 + g_2$ are two such representations. Then $h = f_1 - g_1 = g_2 - f_2$ in $U$. The LHS is holomorphic inside $C_2$ and the RHS is holomorphic outside $C_1$. Therefore $h$ can be extended to an entire function, and since it is holomorphic at infinity, $h$ is constant.